# add variable into variable javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add the qm.negativesData string to qm.data below. But I get a syntax error. Can anyone help me on this one?

```
qm.data = [{
    "xScale":"ordinal",
    "comp":[],
    "main":[{qm.negativesData},{qm.positivesData}],
    "type":"line-dotted",
    "yScale":"linear"}];
```

The qm.negativesData and qm.positivesData contain a string with data to build my graph.

**/// Update**

The output of qm.negativesData for example is:

```
"{"className":".main.l1","data":[{"x":"2013-10-16","y":"3283581"},{"x":"2013-10-17","y":"1512116"},{"x":"2013-10-18","y":"3967"},{"x":"2013-10-19","y":"1094"},{"x":"2013-10-20","y":"853"},{"x":"2013-10-21","y":"1205"},{"x":"2013-10-22","y":"2618700"},{"x":"2013-10-23","y":"3928291"},{"x":"2013-10-24","y":"3670318"},{"x":"2013-10-25","y":"3347369"},{"x":"2013-10-26","y":"2525573"},{"x":"2013-10-27","y":"3224612"},{"x":"2013-10-28","y":"3992964"},{"x":"2013-10-29","y":"3949904"},{"x":"2013-10-30","y":"3568618"},{"x":"2013-10-31","y":"3104696"},{"x":"2013-11-01","y":"3246932"},{"x":"2013-11-02","y":"2817758"},{"x":"2013-11-03","y":"3198856"},{"x":"2013-11-04","y":"3952957"},{"x":"2013-11-05","y":"3934173"},{"x":"2013-11-06","y":"3878718"},{"x":"2013-11-07","y":"3642822"},{"x":"2013-11-08","y":"3388646"},{"x":"2013-11-09","y":"318335"}]}"
```

I think it should not start with " and end with " this causes an error at the moment..  is there a way to exclude the " ?

Comment: What do you mean by "add"?

Comment: -1 because you have not edited your question with what the contents of `negativesData` and `positivesData` are, and the final data structure you want to see. (Is it a single-valued array holding a string? Two strings? Strings split into pieces?)

Comment: @Phrogz I have added the desired update... sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a JavaScript object literal, the curly braces are for key value pairs.  Thus, `{qm.negativesData}` isn't valid.

If you want to set `main` to an array containing the values of `qm.negativesData` and `qm.positivesData`, you can use:

```
qm.data = [{
    "xScale":"ordinal",
    "comp":[],
    "main":[qm.negativesData, qm.positivesData],
    "type":"line-dotted",
    "yScale":"linear"}];
```

Comment: This seemed to work. Finally this was the solution "main": [qm.negativesData] for only 1 variable at the moment.. I'm sure the adding a second variable will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a simple array:

```
qm.data = [{
    "xScale":"ordinal",
    "comp":[],
    "main":[qm.negativesData,qm.positivesData],
    "type":"line-dotted",
    "yScale":"linear"}];
```

This will mean `qm.data.main[0] == qm.negativesData` and `qm.data.main[1] == qm.positivesData`

Or you might want something like this:

```
qm.data = [{
    "xScale":"ordinal",
    "comp":[],
    "main":{
        "negativesData":qm.negativesData,
        "positivesData":qm.positivesData},
    "type":"line-dotted",
    "yScale":"linear"}];
```

This will mean `qm.data.main.negativesData == qm.negativesData` and `qm.data.main.positivesData == qm.positivesData`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to concatenate two arrays into a new one:

```
qm.data = [{
    "xScale":"ordinal",
    "comp":[],
    "main":qm.negativesData.concat(qm.positivesData),
    "type":"line-dotted",
    "yScale":"linear"}];
```

Or use `+` to add together two strings into a new one:

```
qm.data = [{
    "xScale":"ordinal",
    "comp":[],
    "main":qm.negativesData + qm.positivesData,
    "type":"line-dotted",
    "yScale":"linear"}];
```

It's not clear what data you have and (more importantly) what data you want in the end. What does the `main` field of `qm.data` need to look like?

<sub>*P.S. You don't need to quote the names of your keys if they are valid identifiers and this is JavaScript instead of JSON. For example, just `qm.data = [{xScale:"ordinal", comp:[], …}];`*</sub>

Comment: these solution's dont work because we're adding a string starting with " , this causes an error. Is there a way to remove the starting " and ending " from the string?